# Spring Boot: Once Per Request Filter ->Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, filter

I have implemented Once Per Request Filter with following code :

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    httpRequestWrapper = Optional.ofNullable(new HttpRequestWrapper(request));
    if(httpRequestWrapper.isPresent())
    {
    Message message = objectMapper.readValue(httpRequestWrapper.get().getInputStream(), Message.class);
    try
    {
        boolean isAuthenticatedHeader = false;
        RabbitMq.rabbitMqLog(canonicalMessage);
        isAuthenticatedHeader = authenticateAuthHeader(request.getHeader(Constants.AUTH), request.getHeader(Constants.PASS));
        if (isAuthenticatedHeader)
        {
            Logger.logInfo(new LogDetails(CLASSNAME), "Aunthentication successful !!!! ");
            if (Filter.isInValid().test(canonicalMessage))
            {
                throw new BadRequestException();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.logError(new LogDetails(CLASSNAME), " Aunthentication not successful. Please check. ");
            throw new NotAuthorizedException("Unauthorized Access");
        }
        Map<String, String> headers = Collections.list(((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeaderNames()).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(h -> h, request::getHeader));
        headers.updateHeaders(headers);
        filterChain.doFilter(httpRequestWrapper.get(), response);
        RabbitMq.rabbitMqLog();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

}

I m getting below exception once the tomcat is getting started:

```
2018-08-01 15:26:33,563 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1]
servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-08-01 15:26:33,564 INFO  [http-nio-8889-exec-1] [localhost].[/] 
- Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2018-08-01 15:26:33,565 INFO  [http-nio-8889-exec-1] servlet.DispatcherServlet  -
FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-08-01 15:26:33,565 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1]
support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of
singleton bean 'multipartResolver' 2018-08-01 15:26:33,565 DEBUG
[http-nio-8889-exec-1] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Using
MultipartResolver
[org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@4f8969b0]
2018-08-01 15:26:33,566 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1]
support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating instance of bean
'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
2018-08-01 15:26:33,566 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1]
support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of
singleton bean 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor'
2018-08-01 15:26:33,566 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1]
support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of
singleton bean
'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2018-08-01 15:26:33,571 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1]
support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of
singleton bean 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor'
2018-08-01 15:26:33,571 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1]
support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of
singleton bean
```

I tried following:

```
    if (request.getMethod().equals("POST") && (new AntPathRequestMatcher("/transactions/v1/enrichments").matches(request))) {
        httpRequestWrapper = Optional.ofNullable(new HttpRequestWrapper(request));
        if(httpRequestWrapper.isPresent())
        {
        CanonicalMessage canonicalMessage = objectMapper.readValue(httpRequestWrapper.get().getInputStream(), CanonicalMessage.class);
        try
        {
            boolean isAuthenticatedHeader = false;
            eventLogRawDataServiceImpl.eventLogExecution(canonicalMessage);
            isAuthenticatedHeader = authenticateAuthHeader(request.getHeader(Constants.AUTHORIZATION), request.getHeader(Constants.DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN));
            if (isAuthenticatedHeader)
            {
                ondotLogger.logInfo(new LogDetails(CLASSNAME), "Aunthentication successful !!!! ");
                if (CloudServerFilter.isInValid().test(canonicalMessage))
                {
                    throw new BadRequestException();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ondotLogger.logError(new LogDetails(CLASSNAME), " Aunthentication not successful. Please check. ");
                throw new NotAuthorizedException("Unauthorized Access");
            }
            Map<String, String> headers = Collections.list(((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeaderNames()).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(h -> h, request::getHeader));
            cloudServerHeaders.updateHeaders(headers);
            filterChain.doFilter(httpRequestWrapper.get(), response);
            responseHandler.eventLoggerForResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
        }
    }else
    {
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

and this

```
@Configuration
public class CloudServerConfigAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private Filter filter;

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean myFilterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean regBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    regBean.setFilter(filter);
    regBean.setOrder(1);
    regBean.addUrlPatterns("/transactions/v1/enrichments");

    return regBean;
}
```

}

Exception:

```
The Exception comes after wards :
018-08-01 15:26:33,612 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
2018-08-01 15:26:33,628 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter  - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4e982e7d
2018-08-01 15:26:33,647 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter  - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4e982e7d
2018-08-01 15:26:33,648 ERROR [http-nio-8889-exec-1] [/].[dispatcherServlet]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: com.ondot.cloudserver.handlers.HttpRequestWrapper$CachedServletInputStream@34378acb; line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3854)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3799)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2924)
    at com.ondot.cloudserver.handlers.CloudServerFilter.doFilterInternal(CloudServerFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-08-01 15:26:33,657 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2018-08-01 15:26:33,661 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-08-01 15:26:33,667 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2018-08-01 15:26:33,667 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
2018-08-01 15:26:33,667 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2018-08-01 15:26:33,762 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  - Written [{timestamp=Wed Aug 01 15:26:33 IST 2018, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException, message=No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: com.ondot.cloudserver.handlers.HttpRequestWrapper$CachedServletInputStream@34378acb; line: 1, column: 0], path=/health/}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@6c6cb480]
2018-08-01 15:26:33,771 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-08-01 15:26:33,771 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-1] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
2018-08-01 15:26:34,274 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter  - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4e982e7d
2018-08-01 15:26:34,275 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter  - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4e982e7d
2018-08-01 15:26:34,275 ERROR [http-nio-8889-exec-3] [/].[dispatcherServlet]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: com.ondot.cloudserver.handlers.HttpRequestWrapper$CachedServletInputStream@281c1fb0; line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3854)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3799)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2924)
    at com.ondot.cloudserver.handlers.CloudServerFilter.doFilterInternal(CloudServerFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-08-01 15:26:34,282 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2018-08-01 15:26:34,283 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-08-01 15:26:34,284 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2018-08-01 15:26:34,284 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
2018-08-01 15:26:34,284 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2018-08-01 15:26:34,289 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  - Written [{timestamp=Wed Aug 01 15:26:34 IST 2018, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException, message=No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: com.ondot.cloudserver.handlers.HttpRequestWrapper$CachedServletInputStream@281c1fb0; line: 1, column: 0], path=/info}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@6c6cb480]
2018-08-01 15:26:34,289 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-08-01 15:26:34,289 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-3] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
2018-08-01 15:26:34,833 DEBUG [cloudServerDbConnectionPool housekeeper] pool.HikariPool  - cloudServerDbConnectionPool - Before cleanup stats (total=21, active=0, idle=21, waiting=0)
2018-08-01 15:26:34,834 DEBUG [cloudServerDbConnectionPool housekeeper] pool.HikariPool  - cloudServerDbConnectionPool - After cleanup  stats (total=20, active=0, idle=20, waiting=0)
2018-08-01 15:26:34,834 DEBUG [cloudServerDbConnectionPool connection closer] pool.PoolBase  - cloudServerDbConnectionPool - Closing connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5ac8cbc1: (connection has passed idleTimeout)
2018-08-01 15:26:53,477 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter  - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4e982e7d
2018-08-01 15:26:53,478 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter  - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4e982e7d
2018-08-01 15:26:53,478 ERROR [http-nio-8889-exec-2] [/].[dispatcherServlet]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: com.ondot.cloudserver.handlers.HttpRequestWrapper$CachedServletInputStream@76d11ae3; line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3854)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3799)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2924)
    at com.ondot.cloudserver.handlers.CloudServerFilter.doFilterInternal(CloudServerFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-08-01 15:26:53,480 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2018-08-01 15:26:53,480 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-08-01 15:26:53,481 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2018-08-01 15:26:53,481 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
2018-08-01 15:26:53,482 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2018-08-01 15:26:53,486 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  - Written [{timestamp=Wed Aug 01 15:26:53 IST 2018, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException, message=No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: com.ondot.cloudserver.handlers.HttpRequestWrapper$CachedServletInputStream@76d11ae3; line: 1, column: 0], path=/health/}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@6c6cb480]
2018-08-01 15:26:53,487 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-08-01 15:26:53,487 DEBUG [http-nio-8889-exec-2] servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
2018-08-01 15:27:04,835 DEBUG [cloudServerDbConnectionPool housekeeper] pool.HikariPool  - cloudServerDbConnectionPool - Pool stats (total=20, active=0, idle=20, waiting=0)
```

Below is the wrapper code which I m using:

```
    public class HttpRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

private ByteArrayOutputStream cachedBytes;

public HttpRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    if (cachedBytes == null)
        cacheInputStream();

    return new CachedServletInputStream();
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream()));
}

private void cacheInputStream() throws IOException {
    /*Cache the inputstream in order to read it multiple times.*/
    cachedBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(super.getInputStream(), cachedBytes);
}
final class CachedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {
    private ByteArrayInputStream input;

    public CachedServletInputStream() {
        /* create a new input stream from the cached request body */
        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedBytes.toByteArray());
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return input.read();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFinished() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
    }
}
```

}

It helps me cache the Request and Reuse it. Previously I was using Interceptors to authenticate my request. But I need to catch my request and give it to Rabbit MQ for that I shifted to Filters.

Comment: Log which you have added is just INFO and DEBUG  where is Exception ??

Comment: Updated the Post.

Comment: You can only read the body once... You are reading it in your filter and hence the body is already read and there is nothing more to consume.

Comment: I have HTTP Wrapper to read the input stream , I have no issues running the request and getting response . The Exception keeps repeating itself after sometime like its getting popped up in the logs . While my tomcat is working normally giving me response. Strangely this behavior is coming on Linux server , I unable to get it in the Eclipse IDE.